# X Plot vs Y Plot in Excel Where X is not Time

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In school (and on a blog called Indexed) I once this sweet graph where two different criteria make up the X and Y graph on a plot.

Assuming both criteria are good the "no brainer" / "low hanging fruit" is in the quadrant farthest from the origin. The quadrant closest to the origin is the least interest and the other two are trade-offs so to speak.

I realize this is not a single function per se ... but this just seems like 'the money chart' if that makes any sense.

The closest I have seen anyone do this in Excel is by making one of the axis' into time and then creating dummy data points for for all the independent (X axis) variables.

But if you're not doing time on the X-axis it gets tricky because (1) two instances might be at the same spot if they have the same level in both criteria and (2) you might not have anything in a certain place.

My data looks like 2 series info with each row being a different creature.
[image]

And then I want it to look something like this:

[image]

As you can tell I didn't actually try to plot the data in the picture. Also please step around the bad spelling.

**EDIT:**

My question is, how do I create this chart in Excel ?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: How is the data in your image reflecting the data in the table? "Axlotyls" have a `0` value for the Client demand, yet it seems to be say 1/3rd up the Y Axis.  Same with Flying Elk Dogs.  Weasels also have `0` for the Client Demand, yet are on a different plot too...?

Comment: @BruceWayne: Yes, I meant to call that out with, "As you can tell I didn't actually try to plot the data in the picture." If it would help answer my question I could adjust the data.

Comment: It's called a scatter chart

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: Thanks. The first time I tried this with the labels it made the labels into the X-Axis. I tried it again without the labels and it worked! If you want to just put that down below as an answer I'll give you the credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your data, not the label names.

Under the insert tab, find scatter chart, and insert one of these.
click on the chart, then under the design tab, click add chart element, select data labels, and more options.

Look for the option to add labels from cell range. use the cells referring to the labels as the range.

failing that there will be many many simple guides from a quick google search of `how to create a scatter graph in excel` and `use cell range for data labels on excel chart`

I do not have time right now to include images of the steps, but hope this made sense